# Can't download with HttpClient with a different server port

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am using Apache's HttpClient via [httpclient-fluent-builder](http://code.google.com/p/httpclient-fluent-builder/) to download a http page.

This is the code:

```
...
try {
    response = Http.get("http://fr3.ah.fm:9000/played.html")
        .use(client)                // use this HttpClient (required)
        .charset("windows-1252")      // set the encoding... (optional)
        .asString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
Log.i(TAG, ""+ response );
...
```

Problem is that I get org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

It's something with the host:port/url, beacause it works with urls without ports. I also get this same error with another Httphelper class than fluent-builder. Firewall is off.

Logcat: http://pastebin.com/yMMvvdQ3

Comment: If you hit http://fr3.ah.fm:9000/played.html with your browser, it gives you something valid?

Comment: Yes, And I tried it both from my regular browser and the android browser inside the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what it was via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682932/shoutcast-over-ssl) that it was the Shoutcast server...

> You should be able to connect to 8000
>   with your web browser and get the DNAS
>   status page. If, on the other hand,
>   you connect to that port with a media
>   player, it'll return the direct MP3
>   stream. (**Unfortunately, in an
>   incredibly boneheaded piece of design,
>   the way SHOUTcast decides which to
>   respond with is by sniffing your
>   User-Agent header for something
>   beginning with Mozilla**, so if you're
>   using an alternative browser or
>   blocking your UA you'll not be able to
>   get the status, and if the stream's
>   down you might just get nothing.)

Drove me crazy.. But it's an easy fix. I just added.

```
.header("User-Agent", "UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0")
```

Comment: You have no idea how much effort you just saved me. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to set the uri using HttpHost and use it in HttpClient.execute().

I have not tried it..