# Insecure "video" over HTTPS

Tags: html, google-chrome, ssl, https, html5-audio

I have a site that is loading over HTTPS.

I have a HTML5 audio element on that site (currently a fallback for a Flash player), that is loading a Shoutcast URL. The Shoutcast URL is loading using a regular HTTP URL, because it doesn't seem to work using HTTPS.

However, Chrome is showing that the page includes elements that aren't secure, and when I check he console, I see this message:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://shoutcasturl.com:8000/;'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Is there any way to get rid of the error in Chrome, so that the site shows up as fully secure, without any errors?

Shoutcast doesn't seem to work over HTTPS, though I don't think there's a certificate on that server for that FQDN anyway, but it doesn't seem like that adding a SSL certificate to the Shouutcast server will change anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get rid of this warning is to load all external resources from secure locations. Since Shoutcast doesn't support SSL, your site will not be fully secure as long as you are loading assets directly from them.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682932/shoutcast-over-ssl) for some fairly complicated suggestions on getting around the issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's an easy alternative... :(
Thanks a lot!