# Accessing iTunes previewUrl from SSL

Tags: https, itunes-store

I am attempting to play iTunes previews on my website, which is serverd over HTTPS/SSL - partly because of this recommendation https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html by google.

As far as I can tell, the iTunes previewUrl returned by their search API https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/ only returns an http address (and the trivial fix of just transforming the url to https doesn't work).

So my site now generates a whole bunch of errors like this:

song:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.music4dance.net/song' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://a1070.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/093/Music/0c/66/66/mzm.gwwviicr.aac.p.m4a'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
song:1 Mixed Content:

Is there any way to get an HTTPS/SSL reference to this or other way to bypass this error?

I looked at this post: [Insecure "video" over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768568/insecure-video-over-https) and read this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/22/handling-mixed-httpshttps-content/ which gives some background on why this error is generated, but neither seems to lead to a solution for my case.